# Spatie Permissions for Laravel spark resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark, laravel-permission

We are developing an application using larval spark

A user will be able to invited to multiple teams.

With in each team there are a number of venues, we want each user to have specific permissions for that venue.

I.E User will have the edit-venue-details permission for venue A but not for Venue B

Is there a way of linking Spatie permissions to an ID? So we can validate on a per venue basis.

Otherwise if we give a user edit-venue-details permission it will be valid for all of the sites, users will not have the same permissions on each venue.

Answer (score 0):

Spatie/laravel-permission is more concern with high-level permission/roles over certain features

Where the concept you are referring to is known as **Model Policies** which Laravel implements by default you may find more details in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#generating-policies

Find this example maybe it will make it clearer,
https://github.com/drbyte/spatie-permissions-demo/blob/master/app/Policies/PostPolicy.php